# cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: DPI-1047: Cannot locate a 64-bit Oracle Client library UBUNTU

Tags: python, oracle

Hi i got this probleme :
`cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: DPI-1047: Cannot locate a 64-bit Oracle Client library: "/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/server/lib/libclntsh.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory". See https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/installation.html for help`
i searched and tried multiple fixes but none seemed to work i checked multiple time my oracle installation and it's x64 i've setup the correct path with ldconfig and all but it's still not working and i don't know why i can't figure out what's the problem. ( i'm a total beginner )

Comment: Do you have an environment variable ORACLE_HOME pointing to /app/oracle/product/10.2.0/server ?

Comment: nop where do i find that

Comment: Eh in your environment settings…. Otherwise, define one and make it point to where it is in your installation.

Comment: i got this in my env var `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/oracle/instantclient_19_9`

Comment: And there you do find libclntsh.so ?

Comment: nop but i found `oracle/product/10.2.0/server`

Comment: In that case export ORACLE_HOME=/oracle/product/10.2.0/server and unset LD_LIBRARY_PATH. Oracle normally searches in $ORACLE_HOME/lib by default.

Comment: cx_Oracle only works with 11.2 or later Oracle Client libraries.  Install a newer version than 10.2.  The [installation instructions](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/installation.html) have all the details

Comment: thanks a lot guys ! you should make an answer so i can show other people what's the solution

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your environment variable ORACLE_HOME point to an Oracle installation: in your case:

`export ORACLE_HOME=/oracle/product/10.2.0/server`

and correct to unset LD_LIBRARY_PATH.
Oracle by default searches in $ORACLE_HOME/lib for the libraries.

Comment: cx_Oracle needs 11.2 or later Oracle Client

Comment: i did what you said but i replaced /oracle/product/10.2.0/server with /opt/oracle/oracleclient_21_4/ and now i got this error `Cannot locate a 64-bit Oracle Client library: "/opt/oracle/instantclient_21_4//lib/libclntsh.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"`

Comment: what files are available in /opt/oracle/instantclient_21_4/*/* ?

Comment: a lot of `libclnts` `libclntshcore` and `libocci`

Comment: does this article help: https://csiandal.medium.com/install-oracle-instant-client-on-ubuntu-4ffc8fdfda08 ?

Comment: yeah a lot thanks ! it fixes the wrong library problem but now i got this `ORA-12545: Connect failed because target host or object does not exist` but it's not a problem to be fixed here i'll search the error code on internet thanks a lot man !

Comment: nevermind the problem was because i wasn't connected to my database now it works perfectly !! you're a true life savior

Comment: From the [doc](https://python-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/initialization.html) itself:
"Note that the environment variable ORACLE_HOME should only ever be set when you have a full database installation or full client installation (such as installed with the Oracle GUI installer)."